# Angular - Forbidden error after uploading in S3

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm coding a profile section of an Angular app.
This section allows to change the profile **picture**.

I have a User Class that represents the user like that:

```
public name:string = '',
public email:string = '',
public password:string = '',
public picture:string=''
```

The property **picture** respresents a S3 URL. In the HTML I have an instance of that class called model. The part of HTML to manage the **picture** is:

```
<img [attr.src]="model.picture" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">

<label class="btn btn-default">
  <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)">
</label>

<button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!selectedFiles" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

When I show the profile section, the image is shown without problems.

When the button is clicked, the file is uploaded and the property **model.picture** is set with the new URL to make the tag image shows the new photo automatically. This is the code:

```
uploadfile(file, userService: UserRegistrationService, model : UserForm){
  const bucket = new S3(
  {
    accessKeyId: 'access',
    secretAccessKey: 'secret',
    region: 'us-west-2'
  });

  const params = {
    Bucket: 'repo-bucket',
    Key: file.name,
    Body: file,
    ACL: 'public-read'
   };

   if(bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {

     if (err) {
         console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
         return false;
     }   
      //The new URL is set to the property picture
      model.picture="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/repo-bucket/" + file.name;

     userService.updateProfilePhoto(file.name);
     return data;
   })){
       return file.name
  }
     return null;
  }
```

When I click to change the photo, the file is uploaded correctly but the javascript console shows this error when the property **picture** is changed with the new value:

```
GET https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/repo-bucket/http://localhost:4200/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

But if I press F5 to reload the page, the image is shown correctly.

The method userService.updateProfilePhoto is like:

```
updateProfilePhoto(fileName: string){

    let cognitoUser = this.cognitoUtil.getCurrentUser();
    let urlFile = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/repo-bucket/" + fileName;
    cognitoUser.getSession(function (err, session) {
        if (err) {
            alert("Error");
            return;
        }        
        let attributeList = [];
        let dataPicture = {
            Name: 'picture',
            Value: urlFile
        }
        attributeList.push(new CognitoUserAttribute(dataPicture));
        cognitoUser.updateAttributes(attributeList,function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('upload success');
        });
    });
}
```

Could you help me to find what is the problem?
Do you know if there a time to make te photo available?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post method definition of `updateProfilePhoto `?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal Ready. The method updates the picture property in Cognito Service of AWS. Thanks.

Comment: try `this.model.picture = <•••>` instead of `model.picture`

Comment: I have added answer with 2 approaches, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach1:**

```
if(bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {

    ...

    model.picture = data.Location;
    //this.model.picture = data.Location; also try this

    ...
})){
    return file.name
}
```

**Approach2:**

```
if(bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => { <== note callback definition using arrow

    ...
    //The new URL is set to the property picture
    model.picture = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/repo-bucket/" + file.name;

    userService.updateProfilePhoto(file.name);
    return data;
})){
    return file.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. we need to check Bucket having public access or Not.
2. If Bucket doe's not have public means make bucket as public
   3.If Bucket having pubilc  access still getting error means follow below steps
   path==>Goto the your bucket==>permissionTab==>find CROSS TAB add below configaration...

   ## Note: Below configaration "Resource" Replace your bucketName

   ```
   {
     "Version":"2012-10-17",
     "Statement":[
       {
         "Sid":"AddPerm",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
         "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketName/*"]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```